# npm does not support Node.js v0.12.17

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack

I am trying to npm install on my BeagleBoard black but I get this message whenever I run anything with npm

**npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.12.17
 You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
 can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
 You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/**

is this Ian issue I should be concerned about?

Comment: Is there an reason for you to use `Node.js v0.12.17` ? Is no, you should update to the latest version (7.10.0) or the latest LTS (6.10.3)

Answer (score 1):

Node stopped there long term support for version 0.12.17 on December 2016.

Read this for [details](https://nodesource.com/blog/essential-steps-long-term-support-for-nodejs/)